# How to display Firebase query result in HTML (undefined error)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, undefined

I am trying to display Firebase query results in HTML but the browser shows "undefined" instead of the value that I see in the console.

```
var showData = document.getElementById("showData");
var button1 = document.getElementById("but1");

var usersRef = 
firebase.database().ref('stores/').orderByChild("sid").equalTo(123);



function s2_but() {   //function gets trigger when button pressed
    usersRef.on('value', snap);

function snap(data) {
    data2 = data.val();
    console.log(data2);
    showData.innerHTML = data2.sname; //sname is the name of child key 
                                      //whose value I want to show
       }
};
```

Here is what the console shows:

```
entry1: {prod1: "coffee", prod2: "sandwich", sid: 123, 
         sname: "Java Coffee"}
__proto__:Object
```

Therefore, I am able to retrieve the data but I get an undefined in the browser when I use the following code to show the data in HTML.

```
<p id="showData"></p>
```

[Undefined variable showing in the web-browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StjYM.png)
I think the error happens when I am trying to call the exact value from the object using the following code but I am not sure. All the examples I have seen have done it this way. Therefore, I am confused.

```
showData.innerHTML = data2.sname;
```

In the HTML file I have both Firebase and jquery appropriately included, initialized etc.

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
    function snap(data) {
    data2 = data.val();
    data3 = data2.entry1.sname;
    console.log(data3);
    showData.innerHTML = data3;
};
```

Firebase returns a nested object with this query. entry1 is the name of the first level or key of this object. Therefore, its name has to be entered before accessing the value.

What to do if "entry1" were actually defined by a variable?

Comment: Glad you were able to find a solution to this. Regarding your follow-up question, you could go like this: `data2[entry1].sname`.

By the way, it's great to put follow-up questions to answers in the comments section of that answer instead :)

Comment: Thank you! I edited the code as following and it now also works when the first level of data is a variable.     
    function snap(data) {
            data2 = data.val();
            var level1 = 'entry1';
            data3 = data2[level1].sname;
            console.log(data3);
            showData.innerHTML = data3;
    };

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to figure out the best way to do this. It took a while to understand the limitations of Firebase coming from an SQL background.

To query the database, I used this instead of using orderByChild():

```
var sid = 'entry1';
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('stores/' 
+ sid);
```

Now I am able to get the value of sname without having to enter the key of it in the chain:

```
function s2_but() {
usersRef.on('value', snap);
function snap(data) {
    data2 = data.val();
    data3 = data2.sname;
    console.log(data3);
    showData.innerHTML = data3;
};
};
```

This is to query a Firebase database entry that looks   like this. [image]

I hope this helps some of you looking to solve a similar problem. If you have any suggestions please let me know.